# Minimal configuration for rendering to texture on iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, framebuffer

My code:

```
// setup framebuffer
glGenFramebuffers(1, &_internalFramebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, _internalFramebuffer);

// reference texture
glGenTextures(1, &_referenceRectifiedTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _referenceRectifiedTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, width, height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, _referenceRectifiedTexture, 0);

glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// check status
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
  NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status);
  return NO;
}
```

It never passes the status check. Do I need to do something else, in addition to binding the framebuffer and the texture?

Comment: I don't think GL_LUMINANCE is a supported texture format for a render target in OpenGL ES 2. See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688057/which-opengl-es-2-0-texture-formats-are-color-depth-or-stencil-renderable.

Comment: I think I've seen `EXT_texture_rg` used in `GPUImage` in fact. As I have just one value to store per pixel, probably the red channel texture is the only one I can use. Thanks!